# Integrate "Nova Filemanager" with "Nova TinyMCE text editor with images" Package

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to integrate Nova Filemanager with "Nova TinyMCE text editor with images" package? I have tried to search for a solution for this, but couldn't find any.

In NovaTinyMCE.php config file it uses 'use_lfm' to call UniSharp Laravel Filemanager to upload images. but my setup uses Nova Filemanager to upload images. So the question is is it possible to call nova filemanager instead of laravel filemanager?

Settings in NovaTinyMCE.php:

```
$this->withMeta([
            'options' => [
                'content_css' => '/vendor/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css',
                'skin_url' => '/vendor/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide',
                'path_absolute' => '/',
                'plugins' => [
                    'lists preview hr anchor pagebreak image wordcount fullscreen directionality paste textpattern'
                ],
                'toolbar' => 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | image | bullist numlist outdent indent | link',
                'relative_urls' => false,
                'use_lfm' => true,
                'lfm_url' => 'nova-filemanager'
            ]
        ]);
```

Packages Used:
Tiny MCE: https://novapackages.com/packages/emilianotisato/nova-tinymce

Nova Filemanager: https://novapackages.com/packages/infinety-es/nova-filemanager

Answer (score 1):

I added the following URL into the `lfm_url` value and set `use_lfm` to `true`:

```
NovaTinyMCE::make('body')->options([
            'use_lfm' => true,
            'lfm_url' => 'nova/nova-filemanager'
        ]),
```

This does work and pops up with the full admin interface where you can select the URL for the image to insert into the inoutbox, it's not ideal but it works.

For more information, read https://novapackages.com/packages/emilianotisato/nova-tinymce

Comment: I was looking for a way to call the filemanager so users can browse already uploaded images. Still no way to do this right?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it with help of this package : https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/

After following the installation instructions (don't forget to publish the config file and add the route), I edited the config file like that (`config/lfm.php`) :

```php
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Documentation for this config :
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| online  => http://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/config
| offline => vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/docs/config.md
 */

return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Routing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'use_package_routes'       => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Shared folder / Private folder
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If both options are set to false, then shared folder will be activated.
    |
     */

    'allow_private_folder'     => false,

    // Flexible way to customize client folders accessibility
    // If you want to customize client folders, publish tag="lfm_handler"
    // Then you can rewrite userField function in App\Handler\ConfigHandler class
    // And set 'user_field' to App\Handler\ConfigHandler::class
    // Ex: The private folder of user will be named as the user id.
    'private_folder_name'      => UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Handlers\ConfigHandler::class,

    'allow_shared_folder'      => false,

    'shared_folder_name'       => '',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Folder Names
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'folder_categories'        => [
        'file'  => [
            'folder_name'  => '',
            'startup_view' => 'list',
            'max_size'     => 50000, // size in KB
            'valid_mime'   => [
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/gif',
                'image/svg+xml',
                'application/pdf',
                'text/plain',
            ],
        ],
        'image' => [
            'folder_name'  => '',
            'startup_view' => 'grid',
            'max_size'     => 50000, // size in KB
            'valid_mime'   => [
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/gif',
                'image/svg+xml',
            ],
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Pagination
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'paginator' => [
        'perPage' => 30,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Upload / Validation
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'disk'                     => 'public',

    'rename_file'              => false,

    'rename_duplicates'        => false,

    'alphanumeric_filename'    => false,

    'alphanumeric_directory'   => false,

    'should_validate_size'     => false,

    'should_validate_mime'     => false,

    // behavior on files with identical name
    // setting it to true cause old file replace with new one
    // setting it to false show `error-file-exist` error and stop upload
    'over_write_on_duplicate'  => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Thumbnail
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    // If true, image thumbnails would be created during upload
    'should_create_thumbnails' => true,

    'thumb_folder_name'        => 'thumbs',

    // Create thumbnails automatically only for listed types.
    'raster_mimetypes'         => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
    ],

    'thumb_img_width'          => 200, // px

    'thumb_img_height'         => 200, // px

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | File Extension Information
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'file_type_array'          => [
        'pdf'  => 'Adobe Acrobat',
        'doc'  => 'Microsoft Word',
        'docx' => 'Microsoft Word',
        'xls'  => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'xlsx' => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'zip'  => 'Archive',
        'gif'  => 'GIF Image',
        'jpg'  => 'JPEG Image',
        'jpeg' => 'JPEG Image',
        'png'  => 'PNG Image',
        'ppt'  => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
        'pptx' => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | php.ini override
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These values override your php.ini settings before uploading files
    | Set these to false to ingnore and apply your php.ini settings
    |
    | Please note that the 'upload_max_filesize' & 'post_max_size'
    | directives are not supported.
     */
    'php_ini_overrides'        => [
        'memory_limit' => '256M',
    ],
];
```

My `nova-tinymce.php` look like that :

```php
'default_options' => [
    [...]
    'use_lfm' => true,
    'lfm_url' => 'filemanager',
]
```

All my files uploaded by nova-filemanager are put at the root of `/public` directory this is why I set `allow_private_folder` and `allow_shared_folder` to `false` and `shared_folder_name` to an empty string to prevent the creation of new folder when uploading using `lfm`. I also set both `folder_name` key to an empty string (for file and image) to also prevent creation of new folder.

After that I was able to see/edit/add new images in my nova-tinymce.